# how to change the active index of different tabView dynamically in jsf?

Tags: jsf

I have two different tab views. let say t1 and t2. In t1 view,i have 3 tabs(let say A,B,C). how can i navigate to c tab from t2 view dynamically in JSF on click button.I could navigate to different tab if the view is same(t1) using active Index.

Comment: Standard JSF has no tab view component. Are you using PrimeFaces or ICEfaces or? The answer depends on the exact component library which you're actually using.

Comment: yeah..i am trying with prime faces,but couldn't figure it out

Comment: please help me if you know any solution to this issue